# asp.net mvc4 get user information when user reload page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I created custom login which use FormAuthentication. When user use login page, I get user information and save to session variable. If user check remember password, after user close page and reopen, authentication of user is authenticated, in this case, I can not get information of user.

How do I retrieve information of user in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cookies to store user id or something unique. Then get it and query database for example.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

After the user log, I create random TOKEN key, save it into DB to specific user, and add to Respone Cookie (the lifetime of the cookie, you can specify the desired).

Then, when user come again, I get cookie and check it value. If everything is correct, install the session variables.